# how to end the repetition of showing the menu in c++?

Tags: c++

So, I am new to C++. I have this code where I need to input what I would like to view. What happened in my code is that, when I put an input in choice, for example 1, it will show the Peripherals list. And when I input 5 in the Peripheral List, it would go back to the Main Menu. In the Main Menu, if I inputted 4, the Main Menu is looping or repeating again and again. I need to exit it or end if I input 4.

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int choice;
        int pick;
        char view;

        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "\t \t -------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t \t \t WELCOME TO SHOPPING SPREE" << endl;
        cout << "\t \t -------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    //MENU
    do {
        cout << "What type of items would you like to view?" << endl;
        cout << " [1] Peripherals" << endl;
        cout << " [2] Mobile Phones" << endl;
        cout << " [3] Consoles" << endl;
        cout << " [4] Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;


        if (choice == 1) {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "What peripherals would you like to purchase?" << endl;
            cout << "[1] HyperX Alloy FPS PRO" << endl;
            cout << "[2] SteelSeries APEX PRO" << endl;
            cout << "[3] Razer Kraken X" << endl;
            cout << "[4] AORUS K7" << endl;
            cout << "[5] BACK TO MENU" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your choice: ";
            cin >> pick;
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "What mobile phones would you like to purchase?" << endl;
            cout << "[1] Xiaomi Mi Mix 3" << endl;
            cout << "[2] Oppo Reno" << endl;
            cout << "[3] Realme 5" << endl;
            cout << "[4] Samsung Galaxy 10" << endl;
            cout << "[5] BACK TO MENU" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your choice: ";
            cin >> pick;
        }
        else if (choice == 3) {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "What consoles would you like to purchase?" << endl;
            cout << "[1] PlayStation 5" << endl;
            cout << "[2] Nintendo Switch" << endl;
            cout << "[3] PlayStation 4" << endl;
            cout << "[4] XBOX S" << endl;
            cout << "[5] BACK TO MENU" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your choice: ";
            cin >> pick;
        }
    }
    while (pick == 5);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to use more descriptive names: `choice` and `pick` will probably lead to confusion and make updating your code harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *do a thing* when `choice` is 4 (currently you're not doing anything).

That thing is `break`: end the loop.

```
else if (choice == 4) {
   break;
}
```

Alternatively, build it into the loop condition:

```
while (choice != 4 && pick == 5);
```

…though, personally, I think this is harder to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The break in C or C++ is a loop control statement which is used to terminate the loop. As soon as the break statement is encountered from within a loop, the loop iterations stops there and control returns from the loop immediately to the first statement after the loop.

So, you simply can do:

```
cout << "What type of items would you like to view?" << endl;
        cout << " [1] Peripherals" << endl;
        cout << " [2] Mobile Phones" << endl;
        cout << " [3] Consoles" << endl;
        cout << " [4] Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 4) {
            break;
        }
```